# Why is building a Haskell String from Data.Text so slow

Tags: haskell

So I had a location class

```
data Location = Location {
    title :: String
  , description :: String
  }

instance Show Location where
  show l = title l ++ "\n"
         ++ replicate (length $ title l) '-' ++ "\n"
         ++ description l
```

Then I changed it to use `Data.Text`

```
data Location = Location {
    title :: Text
  , description :: Text
  }

instance Show Location where
  show l = T.unpack $
    title l <> "\n"
    <> T.replicate (T.length $ title l) "-" <> "\n"
    <> description l
```

Using criterion, I benchmarked the time taken by `show` on both the `String` and `Data.Text` implementations:

```
benchmarks = [ bench "show" (whnf show l) ]
  where l = Location {
                title="My Title"
              , description = "This is the description."
              }
```

The `String` implementation took 34ns, the `Data.Text` implementation was almost *six times slower*, at 170ns

How do I get `Data.Text` working as fast as `String`?

**Edit: Silly mistakes**

I'm not sure how this happened, but I cannot replicate the original speed difference: now for String and Text I get 28ns and 24ns respectively

For the more aggressive `bench "length.show" (whnf (length . show) l)` benchmark, for String and Text, I get 467ns and 3954ns respectively.

If I use a very basic lazy builder, without the replicated dashes

```
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.Builder as Bldr

instance Show Location where
  show l = show $
    Bldr.fromText (title l) <> Bldr.singleton '\n'
  --  <> Bldr.fromText (T.replicate (T.length $ title l) "-") <> Bldr.singleton '\n'
    <> Bldr.fromText (description l)
```

and try the original, ordinary `show` benchmark, I get 19ns. Now this is buggy, as using `show` to convert a builder to a String will escape newlines. If I replace it with `LT.unpack $ Bldr.toLazyText`, where `LT` is a qualified import of `Data.Text.Lazy`, then I get 192ns.

I'm testing this on a Mac laptop, and I suspect my timings are getting horribly corrupted by machine noise. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: [Data.Text.Lazy.Builder](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.1.3/docs/Data-Text-Lazy-Builder.html): "Efficient construction of lazy Text values"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make it as fast, but you can speed it up some.

#### Appending

`Text` is represented as an array. This makes `<>` rather slow, because a new array has to be allocated and each `Text` copied into it. You can fix this by converting each piece to a `String` first, and then concatenating them. I imagine `Text` probably also offers an efficient way to concatenate multiple texts at once (as a [commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33710015/why-is-building-a-haskell-string-from-data-text-so-slow/33710195#comment55191757_33710015) mentions, you can use a lazy builder) but for this purpose that will be slower. Another good option might be the lazy version of `Text`, which probably supports efficient concatenation.

#### Sharing

In your `String`-based implementation, the `description` field doesn't have to be copied at all. It's just shared between the `Location` and the result of showing that `Location`. There's no way to accomplish this with the `Text` version.

Answer (score 3):

In the String case you are not fully evaluating all of the string operations - (++) and replicate.

If you change your benchmark to:

```
benchmarks = [ bench "show" (whnf (length.show) l) ]
```

you'll see that the String case takes around 520 ns - approx 10 times longer.

Comment: Doing this I find that the String version takes 700ns, and the Text version takes 2600ns, so the problem is clearly in the implementation of show, and not the evaluation - though it clearly helps to call length to ensure things are fully evaluated.